# Bootstrap 4 table too wide for mobile

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have to create a responsive table with bootstrap but it was too wide so i want the td's to be stacked on each other but lso full width in the table Only on mobile. I want to have my TD's Stacked below each other on mobile view. but then they also need to be wide enough for the table. so 100% width in the table. but I can't seem to get it to work.  Here is my HTML code:

```
<table class="table table-responsive w-100 d-block d-md-table">
  <thead class="thead-light">
    <tr>
      <th>Bedrijfsgegevens</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody style="width:100%">
    <tr>
      <td style="font-weight:bold;">Bedrijfsnaam</td>
      <td>~naam_zaak~</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="font-weight:bold;">Straat</td>
      <td>~zaak_straat~</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="font-weight:bold;">Huisnummer</td>
      <td>~zaak_huisnummer~</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="font-weight:bold;">Huisnummer toevoeging</td>
      <td>~zaak_huisnummer_toevoeging~</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="font-weight:bold;">Postcode</td>
      <td>~zaak_postcode~</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="font-weight:bold;">Woonplaats</td>
      <td>~zaak_woonplaats~</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="font-weight:bold;">Land</td>
      <td>~zaak_land~</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="font-weight:bold;">Telefoonnummer</td>
      <td>~zaak_telefoon~</td>
    </tr>
    <thead class="thead-light">
      <tr>
        <th>Correspondentiegegevens</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
      <td style="font-weight:bold;">Straat</td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="~Folder_straat~"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="font-weight:bold;">Huisnummer</td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="~folder_huisnummer~"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="font-weight:bold;">Huisnummer toevoeging</td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="~folder_huisnummer_toevoeging~"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="font-weight:bold;">Postcode</td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="~folder_postcode~"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="font-weight:bold;">Woonplaats</td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="~folder_woonplaats~"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="font-weight:bold;">Land</td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="~folder_land~"></td>
    </tr>
    <thead class="thead-light">
      <tr>
        <th>1e inkoper</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
      <td style="font-weight:bold;">Naam en voorletters</td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="~1e_inkoper_naam~"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="font-weight:bold;">Geslacht</td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="~1e_inkoper_geslacht~"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="font-weight:bold;">Mobielnummer</td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="~zaak_mobiel~"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="font-weight:bold;">E-mailadres</td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="~zaak_emailadres~"></td>
    </tr>
    <thead class="thead-light">
      <tr>
        <th style="font-weight:bold;">2e inkoper</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
      <td style="font-weight:bold;">Naam en voorletters</td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="~2e_inkoper_naam~"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="font-weight:bold;">Geslacht</td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="~2e_inkoper_geslacht~"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="color:red;">
      <td style="font-weight:bold;">Mobielnummer</td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="~zaak_mobiel~"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="color:red;">
      <td style="font-weight:bold;">E-mailadres</td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="~zaak_emailadres~"></td>
    </tr>
    <thead class="thead-light">
      <tr>
        <th>Bedrijfsactiviteit</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Deze informatie helpt ons om<br> gerichter acties en actualiteiten<br> naar je te communiceren.</td>
      <td>
        <div class="form-group">
          <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleTextarea" rows="3"></textarea>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: your code starts with <tr> and ends with </table> ?

Comment: No it starts with this: <table class="table table-responsive w-100 d-block d-md-table">
      <thead class="thead-light">
        <tr>
          <th>Bedrijfsgegevens</th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody style="width:100%">

Comment: @DuncanSpiegelaar I added the missing code to your question. Please do not post missing code in comments but update your question's code. Otherwise it is hard to keep track on the big picture.

Comment: You shouldn't put `thead` in `tbody` ...`The <thead> tag must be used in the following context: As a child of a <table> element, after any <caption>, and <colgroup> elements, and before any <tbody>, <tfoot>, and <tr> elements.`